# Array of string lengths using Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, for-loop

I have an array of strings, and I want to return an array of their lengths. Of course I could do a for loop and iterate, however I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution, like using Linq, or some other fast/pretty one-liner.

Comment: Could you give us some example? it will be good if you provide some sample and expect result

Comment: FYI: "_some other fast_" Note that Linq rarely, if ever, is faster than doing the same thing in an equivalent for/foreach/while loop. Sure, if a loop is gunked up with bad and crappy code that performs like a sea cucumber on the hot asphalt of a racetrack, so to speak, then Linq is obviously being faster. But that doesn't mean Linq would be faster than a loop; it would simply mean that Linq is faster than terribly terrible code, loops or not...

Comment: @elgonzo great observation. Generally I am just trying to learn more ways to do certain tasks, compare the speeds, see how 'pretty' the code looks, etc.

Comment: Take a look at @EvanTrimboli's answer below.  It *almost* answers your question (as discussed in the comments).  His `words.Select` function returns a collection of lengths, but not an array of lengths.  If your goal is something you can iterate over, you are all set, but if you need an Array, you need to follow the lead of some of the comments and add `.ToArray()` at the end.  Note that taking a collection and turning it into an array probably doubles your execution time (since the array must be constructed from the collection and the data in the collection copied to the array)

Comment: You can of course write your entire code into a single line. However I can´t see any benefit in doing so. Doing this with linq may be a **bit** nicer, but **definitly** neither faster, less memory-consuming nor anything else. In fact there is no way to perform some operation all all elements of your array without looping it in some way.

Comment: @Flydog57 calling `ToArray` won´t "double" execution-time. It just materializes the elements and thus iterates the original collection - which you have to do earlier or later anyway. In fact this can lead to even **less* time, because you materialize the list only once, not on every call to `iterator.MoveNext`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: `words.Select(s => s.Length);` will create an IEnumerable that represents the actions required.  Calling `.ToArray()`, will construct an array, but that needs a length, so the array's length needs to be evaluated before the array needs construction - that likely requires a pass through the list (unless there's an optimization for arrays).  Then you need to pass through the list, calculating the string lengths and placing them in the array.  At that point, the OP is likely going to foreach through the array.  In my head that operation is about 2x-ish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Select` function to "transform" each item into another value:

```
var words = new[] { "some", "words", "go", "here" };
var lengths = words.Select(s => s.Length);
```

Comment: I suggest to modify the second Line to `int[] lengths = words.Select(s => s.Length).ToArray();` since OP likes to have an Array of values.

Comment: I mean this is linq/one-liner but still what it does is just simply a loop over all strings within words, right?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I asked for. @Zeta if you can suggest some other variant, it would be interesting.

Comment: @NeNenne.  Take a look at my comment on your question.  You actually asked for an array of lengths.  You don't really want one (you can achieve what you want without one, and creating the array will slow you down).

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code:

```cs
var stringArray = new string[] {"1","12","123","1234"};
stringArray.AsParallel().ForAll(z => Console.WriteLine(z.Length));
```

The output should then be:

```
4
2
3
1
```

Comment: you can populate the result to an array off course :) , ForAll() is accepting Action delegate so you are free to do as you wish